# FileCopy - Automatically TRY AGAIN whenever an unexpected error occurs (0X8007003B)

Tags: excel, vba

I searched for hours but cannot find a solution. Hoping I can get the answer here.

I am doing a FileCopy through VBA and wants the code to automatically Try Again whenever an "unexpected network error has occurred" error happens. Can this be done via VBA?

Note that I have access to the network folder, the error is just common due to VPN connectivity issues.

```
    file_ext = "*.xlsx"

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=dummy_source_path & "\" & file_ext, _
    Destination:=dummy_path
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure destination `dummy_path` ends with "\" and it is not set as read only .. Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method) .. May be overwrite

Comment: Dummy path ends with a "\" all the other files are being copied. There are just instances that this error happens. Is there a way to TRY AGAIN automatically?

Comment: It is also not read only. My question is the TRY AGAIN part.

Comment: I don't know how excel VBA will do that but refer [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/large-file-transfer-failure-error-0x8007003b/1946f3b3-779c-46f4-8329-2f7154ace974) for the error code in your screen shot. Though I wonder, it not a large file (only 2.90 MB)

Comment: I feel like the Application.DisplayAlerts = False has done the trick. Also, my internet could be just slow plus the VPN I am connecting to is also slow.

Comment: I was not sure if `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will help. Glad to learn that . Thanks

Comment: That looks like a shell copy dialog as FSO doesn't do error dialogs. That code is not running.

Comment: @Mark yes you are right. Because I was not really accurate with my post. I manually copied the files and assumed it will happen with an FSO code in the VBA code. So the Application.DisplayAlerts = False has not done the trick? The FSO code will try and try and try again?

Comment: FSO will error. You catch the error and do whatever - See help file for FSO http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe. ---- Explorer is a namespace explorer. Shell namespaces are not all files and folders, eg My Computer. You can use shell functions that act like you are a user (although they have options to hide dialogs) or file functions that only act on files and error on error.

Comment: You can always [shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) out to an external program to do the file copy. Robocopy has several features for robust file copying.